# How to dynamically populate the condition method argument in a Dynamic Query

Tags: 7, database

I am writing a query that will retrieve nodes that match a set of criteria. Though the number of cirteria is unknown. I was hopping i could pass to the `condition()` method an array of criteria with a key as the 'column name' and that value as the 'value to match' for that colum. For instance :

```
$criteria = array ('nid' => 1, 'etid' => '1')

$query = db_select('table', 't');

$query
  ->condition( $criteria)
  ->fields('t', some_field);
```

I have almost 10 criteria and no way to know which will be selected so writing a query for each wont be possible.

Is there a way to achieve that ?

**EDIT:**

i thought about using that :

```
if (empty($criteria1)){
    $criteria = array (":criteria1"= '*');
}else {
 $criteria = array (":criteria1"=$criteria1);
}
$query = db_query('SELECT nid FROM { parce_index } WHERE criteria1 = :criteria1 AND criteria2= criteria2...',$criteria));
```

Would that make sense ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone ever need that i got an answer there.

http://drupal.org/node/12843

This is useful as well :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7476611/how-to-write-a-query-with-a-dynamic-where-clause